# How can I imply Stream for struct which need mutable borrow itself?

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime

Assume that we have a BinaryReader which contains a async method read_next

```rust
impl<R: AsyncRead + AsyncSeek + Unpin + Send> BinaryReader<R> {
    // ......
    async fn read_next(&mut self) -> Result<Option<OwnedEvent>, Error> {
        // ......
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Then I want to imply trait `Stream` for it, in this situation I may use an **additional** field to store the future which was called and pinned before, so that we can consume and return it when next wake.

> So is there a way to directly support Stream without the need for a wrappers?

Then I tried to introduce a wrapper:

```rust
#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct BinaryReaderWrapper<R: AsyncRead + AsyncSeek + Unpin + Send> {
    #[pin]
    inner: BinaryReader<R>,
    #[pin]
    last_fut: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Option<OwnedEvent>, Error>>>>>
}

impl<R: AsyncRead + AsyncSeek + Unpin + Send> Stream for BinaryReaderWrapper<R> {
    type Item = Result<Option<OwnedEvent>, Error>;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        //                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
        let mut this = self.project();

        if this.last_fut.is_none() {
            let ret = Box::pin(this.inner.read_next());
            
            *this.last_fut = Some(ret);
            //                    ^^^ lifetime may not live long enough
            //                    ^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
        }

        let result = ready!(this.last_fut.as_pin_mut().unwrap().poll(cx));

        this.last_fut = None;

        result
    }
}
```

But this won't work, the error messages printed by the compiler is marked in the code above.

I can't figure out why lifetime is mismatch here. It seems like `BoxFuture` need a `'static`, but read_next called on a mutable reference of inner, which only has a limited lifetime. But why?

> When I change Box::pin(this.inner.read_next()) to Box::pin(async_func_without_a_receiver()), everything seems ok.

So does anyone know how to write a proper implementation for Stream in this situation?

Comment: Minor nitpick: `impl` stands for "implement", not "imply"

Comment: This is a complex situation. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe as a link to https://play.rust-lang.org/. It's really hard to help you without being able to play around with your code.

Comment: @Finomnis Thank you for your reply! I have solved it by use a tip given by [alice](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-i-imply-stream-for-struct-which-need-mutable-borrow-itself/80758/2?u=zhouplus). In short, use tokio's reusable-boxfuture to avoid directly self-referential.

Comment: As for the English words, I have write `implement` to my note :p  thanks again! XD